# Vulkan use-cases for lazy init VkObjects

Tags: c++, vulkan

When you are writing some wrappers around basic Vulkan objects like `VkDevice`, `VkSemaphore`, `VkImage` etc. etc. are there some typical use cases (like when using OpenGL), where you would really like to use *lazy initialization* and do not call `vkCreateDevice`, `VkCreateSemaphore`, `VkCreateXyz` directly in the constructor but in some create/init method later?

Answer (score 1):

Lazy initialization is generally used to 'hold off' performing some activity until it actually needed (which could possibly be never).  For creation methods there seem little or no benefit - if you create something you generally want it there and then, or to fail immediately if there is some problem (not later in execution).

However this approach is useful for accessors that invoke Vulkan API methods that may or may not be used by the application, the properties of the physical device for example:

```java
private VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures features;

public VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures features() {
    if(features == null) {
        features = new VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures();
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures(handle, features);
    }
    return features;
}
```

This is nicer than 'forcing' the features to be retrieved from Vulkan as part of the constructor and the results can be cached (as above) if required, at the expense of a little extra complexity.

> EDIT: A better example would probably be the device memory properties or something similar, the features would usually be used immediately when creating the logical device.

For objects that are created via a `VkCreateXXX` method I would suggest both a constructor *and* a static factory method.  Unit-tests would use the constructor (which would generally be protected in some way) whereas an application would invoke the factory.

e.g. (pseudo-code):

```java
class LogicalDevice {
    public static LogicalDevice create(PhysicalDevice parent) {
        // populate VkDeviceCreateInfo with required extensions, layers, queues, etc
        vkCreateDevice(...);
        return new LogicalDevice(...);
    }

    LogicalDevice(Handle handle, PhysicalDevice parent, ...) {
    }
}
```

Comment: "*the properties of the physical device for example*" That makes no sense. The thing you do immediately after getting device properties is *create a device*. If you don't lazily create a device, what's the point in lazily getting the parameters for device creation?

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't follow you.  In the example the physical device features can **only** be invoked after you've created that device, hence I used it as an example of some property that _could_ be lazily accessed.  They have nothing to do with _creating_ the physical device.

Comment: ... that's not how `vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures` works. You give it a `VkPhysicalDevice`, not a `VkDevice`. You use this to get what capabilities a physical device provides, and you select from that set of capabilities which ones your logical device will use. You *have to* get the physical device properties before creating the device.

Comment: Er yes I know, sorry still not following what this has to do with lazy instantiation.

Comment: You said that lazy allocation should not be used for device creation, but you said that it makes sense for querying device properties. But querying device properties is needed *before* you can do device creation, so you're going to *immediately* use the results of the lazy query to create the non-lazy device. Thus, making the entire operation non-lazy. So what was the point of the lazy query?

Comment: Maybe the physical device features was a bad example, a better one might have been `vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties` or the memory properties or something like that.  Also you don't **need** to retrieve the features to create the logical device (though you generally would).

Comment: But that's another function you have to call before device creation. What is the point of doing it lazily to feed a non-lazy operation. If you aren't going to activate extensions, just don't call it. And if you are going to activate extensions, you need to call it *first* to find out if the extensions you're interested in are available.

Comment: What about command buffers? But still I do not see any point in lazy init them, because you could simply create and allocate them when you have some job to place in them...